# passing index and calling a function through dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, dropzone

Everything here is technically working as it should be, but I have one glaring issue: When I add an image to my Dropzone instance, I want it to add the file name of that image to my `cards` array under `imageInfo`.

I can't figure out how to call an independent function through Dropzone though.

Specifically, all I need to figure out here is how I can call my `imageChange` function with `file` from Dropzone as well as `card` as it's in the loop.

How can I call that function with both attributes upon added image?

```js
new Vue({
      mixins: [VueClickaway.mixin],
      components: {},
      el: "#commonNameDiv",
      data() {
        return {
          searchString: [''],
          results: [],
          savedAttributes: [],
          cards: [],
          showList: false,
          zoneNumber:[],
          imageZoneNames: [],
          imageInfo: [] 
        }           
      },
      methods: {
        imageChange(file){
            console.log('it worked');
        },
        autoComplete(ev, card) {
          this.results = [];
          console.log(this.searchString);
          if (ev.target.value.length > 2) {
            axios.get('/product/parts/components/search', {
              params: {
                searchString: ev.target.value
              }
            }).then(response => {
              card.results = response.data;
              this.showList = true;
              console.log(this.results);
              console.log(this.searchString);
            });
          }
        },
        saveAttribute(result, card) {
          card.value = result.attribute_value;
          card.results = [];
          card.zone = this.zoneNumber;
          this.showList = false;
        },
        addCard: function() {
            this.cards.push({
              index: "",
              value: "",
              zoneNumber: "",
              results: [],
              componentImage:"",
              imageInfo: ""
            });
            
             // Index of the last card pushed
            let cardIndex = this.cards.length - 1;
            let instance = this; // $vm
            Vue.nextTick(function () {
              new Dropzone("#dropzone-"+cardIndex, {
                maxFilesize: 12,
                renameFile: function (file) {
                    var dt = new Date();
                    var time = dt.getTime();
                    return time + file.name;
                },
                acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",
                addRemoveLinks: true,
                timeout: 50000,
                removedfile: function (file) {
                    console.log(file.upload.filename);
                    var name = file.upload.filename;

                    var fileRef;
                    return (fileRef = file.previewElement) != null ?
                        fileRef.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;

                },
                init: function() {
                    this.on("addedfile", 
                    function(file) { 
                        instance.imageZoneNames.push({name: file.upload.filename});
                        console.log(file);
                        console.log(instance.imageZoneNames);

                    });
                }
            });
            });

            console.log('cards here');
            console.log(this.cards);
        },
        hideDropdown() {
          this.showList = false;
        },

      },
      created() {

        let instance = this;

        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
      

        this.addCard();

       }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"> </script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.5.0/dropzone.js"></script>


<div id="commonNameDiv">
<div class="uk-grid" v-for="(card, i) in cards" :key="i">
                <div class="uk-width-1-10"  >
                    <input v-model=" card.zoneNumber" size="4" type="text" name="mapNumber">
                </div>
                <div class="uk-width-6-10">
                    <input
                      style="width:100%"
                      placeholder="what are you looking for?"
                      v-model="card.value"
                      v-on:keyup="autoComplete($event, card)"
                    >
                    <div v-if="showList" v-on-clickaway="hideDropdown" class="panel-footer componentList" v-if="card.results.length">
                      <ul>
                        <li  v-for="(result, i) in card.results" :key="i">
                          <a v-on:click="saveAttribute(result, card)">@{{ result.attribute_value }}</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="uk-width-3-10">
                    <form v-on:change="imageChange(card)" method="post" action="{{url('product/parts/upload/store')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data"
                          class="dropzone" v-bind:id="'dropzone-'+i" v-model="card.imageInfo">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div style="height: 35px;">
                
            </div>

            <div>
                <a v-on:click="addCard">Add another zone</a>
            </div>>
</div>
```

Comment: `<form>` doesn't normally emit `change` events, and `v-model` doesn't apply there. How are you invoking `imageChange()`?

Comment: Well that's my issue right now @tony19, I was trying to invoke it that way, but I really don't know the best course now. The dropzone action of this.on("addedfile", is being called when I add an image, but I don't know how I can also incorporate the card as an attribute for that call

Comment: @tony19 if I could find a way to use the card attribute on that call or grab the nearest card index on that call then it would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `addCard` method already has access to the `card` instance being added to `this.cards`, so you could pass that `card` into the callback for the `addedfile` event. For example, you could add a `filename` prop to the `card` instance, and then the `addedfile` callback could update that prop with info from the `file` event argument:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    addCard() {
      //...

      const card = {
        //...
        filename: '',
      }
      this.cards.push(card)

      new Dropzone('#dropzone', {
        init() {
          this.on('addedfile', file => {
            card.filename = file.upload.filename
          })
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/QWNdaWz?editors=1010)

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much, I still have a lot to learn in the way of callbacks actually because this his been the answer to a couple of my issues in recent months. I really appreciate the explaination here as well

Comment: I also recommend using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) in your callbacks to avoid the reference to the component instance (obviates `let instance = this`), and it also usually shortens your code.